# Why is it going to Anaconda and how can I fix it?

Tags: django

[image]

Why is it going to Anaconda and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just use `python manage.py ...` - remove the ".\"?

Comment: Code is preferred to images as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Answer (score 0):

That's because your current path directory has not manage.py .
run command `ls` and verify that can you see `manage.py`.
If there is no `manage.py` then change your path